# No vendor file in Laravel Project (error with PHP version)

Tags: php, laravel-5

I wanted to create a Laravel project today, And I noticed that I was missing the 'vendor' file. I already tried updating the composer, but I always receive this error about my php version: [Terminal picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V05zZ.png)

I'm using Xampp to run the PHP and it uses this version : [Php info page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlXwY.png)

So I assume my xampp server is using the lasest php version but my system isn't. How Do I update my own php version? I'm on windows.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably got two separate PHP versions installed. Search your filesystem and see if multiple results don't come up.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not know where the folder containing PHP lives, unless you tell it.

My guess is that you have updated your Windows PATH sometime in the past to point to an older version of PHP.

So check your Windows PATH and amend the path to point to your new XAMPP/PHP folder.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but wasn't sure. I had the php version from another service application linked to the php version. I changed it and now it works. Thanks!